# Configure Yii2 Advanced on single domain with multiple backends

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

From: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx/#hh2

It works but I have created another backend.

This is the `.htaccess` configuration that I have:

```
RewriteEngine On    

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend2)/web/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]  

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^backend(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]
RewriteRule ^backend2(/(.*))?$ backend2/web/$3 [S=2] 

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0    

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```

Final frontend URL: `http:// example.com/` -> OK.

Final backend URL: `http:// example.com/backend` -> Error 404.

Final another backend URL: `http:// example.com/backend2` -> OK.

Comment: Why `S` flags? Use [L] in both cases.

Comment: what is [L]? I dont know it. I'm learning Yii2. Help me

Comment: `L` means `Last` so when this rule matches it stops processing the other rules. This is not a matter of Yii 2, it's Apache rewrite module - see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `.htaccess` according to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend|backend2)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=2]) two following rules, if current matched
RewriteRule ^backend(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=2]

# Handle the case of backend2, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^backend2(/(.*))?$ backend2/web/$2 [S=1]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```

You need to edit `backend2/config/main.php`:

```
....
    'components' => [
        ....
        'request'=>[
            'baseUrl'=>'/backend2',
        ],
        'urlManager'=>[
            'scriptUrl'=>'/backend2/index.php',
        ],
        // use the following, if you want to enable speaking URL for the backend
//        'urlManager' => [
//            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
//            'showScriptName' => false,
//        ],
    ],
```

Also, you need to create `environments/dev/backend2` and `environments/prod/backend2` folders with appropriate content and fix all namespaces and paths to backend2.